# При клике сменить тег DIV на TEXTAREA

Tags: javascript, html, input, textarea, click

Есть такая форма:

```html
<form>
  <div id="message">
    <div>Тут мои функции </div>
    <input id="send" type="button" value="отправить">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Нужна так сделать чтоб при клике в **Input** отправить

**div id="message"** сменился  на **TextArea id="message"**

Вот таким способам:

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="message">
    <div>Тут мои функции</div>
    <input id="send" type="button" value="отправить">
  </textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем уже нашел решил проблему 
вот готовый код если кому нужно такая функция

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#bdF77").click(function() {
    $('div#message').each(function() {

      $(this).replaceWith("<textarea id='message' name='message' class='manFl'>" + $(this).html() + "</textarea>");

    });


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="message">
  <div class="soderjimoe">Содержимое при клике не меняется, меняется только тег DIV на TEXTAREA и совсеми идом и наме</div>

</div>

<input type="button" value="GONDER" id="bdF77">
```

Answer (score 0):

Начнём с того, что в `textarea` отображается только текст. Ваш `div` и `input` после замены будут в нём отображаться в виде HTML кода, не более.
Саму же замену можно легко сделать при помощи jQuery.

```
$("#message").replaceWith('<textarea id="message"><div>Тут мои функции</div><input id="send" type="button" value="отправить"></textarea>');
```

**UPD: Для комментария.**

Если в исходном теге присутствует JavaScript и его обязательно нужно сохранить в тексте:

```
$("#message").replaceWith(function(index, oldHTML){ return $("<textarea>").html(oldHTML);})
```

Чтобы код работал при клике на `input` его нужно вызвать при обработке события `onclick`.

Comment: вы мне не поняли тут тег целиком не надо менять, а то тут где написано * (тут мои функции)*  много *HTML*  тегов есть, куда их все менять. здесь надо менять при клике INPUT только сам атрибут тега * div /div *  на  * textarea /textarea*

Comment: @SamirMamedov, у Вас **все теги с функционалом вложены в тот тог, который предстоит заменить**. Именно поэтому после замены на textarea они превратятся в обычный текст (код сохранится, но отображаться будет только в виде простого текста). Посмотрите, пожалуйста, внимательно, на Вашу же собственную разметку. Если Вы хотите **чтобы после замены все упомянутые теги отображались как положено, вынесите их за пределы заменяемого тега**.

Comment: давайте я вам объясню по подробнее .тут при изменении тега div на textarea, я тоже знаю что содержимое будет видно в виде html текста,

Comment: давайте я вам объясню по подробнее .тут при изменении тега div на textarea, я тоже знаю что содержимое будет видно в виде html текста, это нечего страшного. мне так и надо чтоб после всех манипуляции, при нажатие на инпут тег div стала  textarea , это из за того что, это форма работает на сервере внутри тега textarea, если все это функции будет внутри тега div при отправке на сервер будет пустыми. вы скажете что почему сразу не написать все функции внутри тега TEXTAREA? потому что тут есть пользовательские   выборы , функции который работает с скриптом, если внутри TEXTAREA событие не работает

Comment: вот я нашел одну но она действует при загрузке страницу, а мне надо чтоб при клике действовал .вот код ` <div id="message">
<div>funksiyalar</div>
</div>
 
<input id="inputid" type="button" value="отправить"> <script>

$("div#tetstid").replaceWith(function(index, oldHTML){
  return $("<textarea>").html(oldHTML);
});

</script>`

Comment: Ну, если такое положение дел с HTML Вас вполне устраивает - не вопрос! Что касается кода. Для того чтобы решить Вашу задачу вовсе необязательно использовать столь сложные конструкции. Всё, ИМХО, гораздо проще (см. ответ).

Comment: @ Streletz уважаемый вы то что написали это при загрузке страницу сразу меняется , а мне надо чтоб при клике в инпут отправить, div тег менялся на textarea не меняя внутренний содержимое. даже не подходит такой способ чтоб менять целиком вот таком виде <div>содержимое</div> на  <textarea>содержимое</textarea> должно меняться только  тег div на  textarea

Comment: @SamirMamedov, **в примечании к ответу написано как сделать так, чтобы код отрабатывал при клике на input**. Внутренне содержимое изменяемого тега при использовании моего способа не изменяется как при той постановке задачи, которая была изложена Вами изначально, так и в случае необходимости сохранения JavaScript (добавил в примечание). В чём проблема? Не знаете как обработать событие `onclick`?

Comment: если знал бы почему у вас спрашивал. я с скриптами не очень .